# Formik not displaying on a nextjs page?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, formik

I have a "Login" component which has a div with Formik inside it, just some first-last name and email form, there are no errors but the Formik component isn't displaying at all, it is just an empty div, anything else works perfectly. Here's a piece of code, maybe I am missing something:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import Head from "next/head";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import Login from "../components/Login";

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>login page</title>
            </Head>
            <h1>hello</h1>
            <Login />
        </>
    );
}
```

And the Login component itself:

```
import { Formik } from "formik";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

const Login = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Formik
                initialValues={{ firstName: "", lastName: "", email: "" }}
                onSubmit={data => {
                    console.log(data);
                }}
            >
                {({ values, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit }) => {
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <TextField
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            value={values.firstName}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            value={values.lastName}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            value={values.email}
                        />
                    </form>;
                }}
            </Formik>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

So the `<h1>hello</h1>` is present on the page, and the empty div which is supposed to have that Login component inside it is present too.
What could the problem be? Maybe I am just blind and missing something simple or is there some sort of package problem?

Comment: Do you have some error in console?

Comment: @LazarNikolic No, only some irrelevant warning.

Comment: That is odd. The only thing that comes to my mind is that you could have imported it wrongly. Could you use maybe absoluth path instead of relative one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the JSX inside your `Formik` children callback.

```js
{({ values, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit }) => {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <!-- Rest of the form -->
        </form>
    );
}}
```

Or the shorthand syntax:

```js
{({ values, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <!-- Rest of the form -->
    </form>
)}
```

Comment: Omg, thanks, I forgot that it's even a function... I feel so stupid, thanks lol